Alternatives to solve these ODEs
I am trying to model some physical phenomena using the following ODE : $f'' = 1/f$ with initial conditions $f(0) = 1/10 , f'(0) = 0$. I have solved it nummerically on a computer and also tried to linearize about a critical point. However there is no exact critical points and in the case the trajectory does not move the most is for points of the form $(M,0)$ where the larger the magnitude of M, the more sense it makes for the point to be almost critical. But these points are far away from my initial condition so I dont think it would even be worth linearizing about them. I also tried to guess a form for the solution, like a power function but I cant find any expression for f. Can anyone provide me a hand to find f?Ps: The actual equation I am trying to solve is the problem $f'' = 1/f -uf', u>0$ with the same initial conditions, but I thought maybe finding a closed form for the first problem could guide me through this more difficult one-

The solution to your equation uses the inverse error function.

@ТymaGaidash ... You have to replace "%3D" with "=".

@GEdgar It seems that when pasting the link into the comments, it changes the input on Wolfram Alpha, but pasting it into the URL works fine. New edited link

Try doing this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y+y’’=1 inside of ` marks to prevent mark-down.

Regarding the last sentence: Scaling $f$ and $x$ appropriately normalizes $f'' = \frac1f-uf'$ to $u = 1$. Then, in terms of $g(x) = e^x f(x)$, the equation becomes $g'' = \frac1g$, so the nominally more difficult equation is essentially the same as the simpler equation $f'' = \frac1f$.

After using Travis's substitution and reducing to $f'' = 1/f$, you can multiply through by $f'$ and integrate to obtain $\frac{1}{2}(f')^2 = \ln|f| + C$. Taking the square roots leads to a separable equation that likely results in some error functions

@whpowell96 Will that work in this case? If we multiply through by $f'$, at the origin (where the initial values are specified) we're multiplying by $f'(0) = 0$.

I think if you carefully perform the integration and express $C$ in terms of the initial condition then it works. At the very least, it results in the same solution form as the answer below. Whether this introduces uniqueness problems I am not sure.

Multiplying both sides of $f''=\frac1f$ by $f'$ gives
$$ ((f')^2)'=2(\ln|f|)'. \tag1$$
Integrating (1) from $0$ to $x$ gives
$$ (f'(x))^2-(f'(0))^2=2(\ln|f(x)|-\ln|f(0)|) $$
or
$$ (f'(x))^2=2(\ln|f(x)|+\ln(10)). \tag2$$
From (2) one has
$$ \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{\ln|f(x)|+\ln(10)}}=\sqrt2. \tag3 $$
Integrating (3) gives
$$ x=\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_{1/10}^{f(x)} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\ln|y|+\ln(10)}}=\frac{1}{10} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2 } \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\ln (10 f(x))}\right). $$

Nice! However, when evaluating f(0) should it not be 1/10 instead?

I used your initial condition.

Oh yeah, I didn’t realize you took out the - sign

"Finding a closed form for the first problem could guide through this more difficult one" ? In fact what you call "tne more difficult problem" has the same level of difficulty than what you call "the first" problem. The main difficulty is in inverting a special function of the Error Function kind.
$$\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{f(t)}-u\frac{df}{dt}\tag 1$$
You didn't say what is $u$. I suppose that it is a constant. If so the ODE is of the autonomous kind. The usual way to reduce order is :
Let $\frac{df}{dt}=Y(f(t))\quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2f}{dt^2}=\frac{dY}{df}\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{dY}{df}Y.\quad$ Eq.$(1)$ becomes :
$$Y\frac{dY}{df}=\frac{1}{f}-u\,Y\qquad (u=\text{constant})$$
This is a first order non-linear ODE.
$$\left(\frac{dY}{df}+u\right)Y-\frac{1}{f}=0 \qquad (u=\text{constant})\tag 2$$
In order to make it on a more usual form one changes the symbols :
$\quad \begin{cases}
f\equiv x\\
Y(x)=y(x)+u\,x
\end{cases}$
$$\left(y(x)+u\,x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$
The classical solving leads to :
$$y(x)=-\frac{2}{u}\frac{e^{\:x^2/2}}{\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\:\text{erfi}(x\sqrt{2})+c\right)}\tag 3$$
$c$ is an arbitrary constant.
$y(x)=y(f)$ is the inverse function of $f(y)$.
For the special function erfi see for example : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html
In theory the original ODE is solved. But in practice coming back to the original notations would involve too arduous calculus. So it seems that numerical calculus is the reasobable way.
